# Variance of a fluctuating number of random variables

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_i$ are not-independent random variables, and $N$ an integer random variable. I now define the "composite" random variable
$$
Y(N) = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \;,
$$
and I want to calculate
$$
\text{Var}[Y(N)] = ...
$$

I'm interested in the specific situation where $\langle X_i^k \rangle$ is independent on $i$, and interested in obtaining an expression involving moments of the distributions for $X$ and $N$.

Is there any trick to derive a compact form for this variance?

EDIT: at the end I might want to consider N from a Binomial distribution.

Comment: It may get useful to condition on $N$ : $\mathbb E[(Y-\mathbb E[Y])^2] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[(Y-\mathbb E[Y])^2|N]]=\mathbb E[ \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N \mathrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j) ]$ now you can replace with what you know about the $X_i$ and with a bit of luck it can simplify.

Comment: I know that $\text{Cov[X_i,X_j]}$ is independent on $i, j$.

Comment: What does this mean?: **the specific situation where $\langle X_i^k \rangle$ is independent on $i$** Also, how is $N$ related to the $X_i$ variables? Independent?

Comment: @Michael, I mean that they come from the same distribution. Giving $\langle X_1 \rangle = \langle X_2 \rangle = ...$ and so for all moments. N is independent on X.

Comment: The answer generally depends on the joint distribution of $X$s.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for $i\neq j$, $\mathrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=a$ is independent on $i$ and $j$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X_i)=b$ is independent of $i$. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[(Y-\mathbb E[Y])^2] &= \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[(Y-\mathbb E[Y])^2|N\right]\right]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[ \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N \mathrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j) \right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[N a + N(N-1) b\right]\\
&= \mathbb E[N] (a-b) + \mathbb E[N^2] b
\end{align*}
You can then compute the first and second moment of $N$ to get your answer.